# Nested get / update function using sql predicate in hazel cast

Tags: java, sql, serialization, hazelcast

Is it possible to query inside the nested list of objects (i.e) lets consider the following example,

```
class A implements Serializable{
   public int id;
   public List<B> incomingBs;
   public A(int x){ this.id=x; }
}

class B implements Serializable{
   public int id;
   public List<A> outgoingAs;
   public B(int x){ this.id=x; }
}
```

I came to know If there is a object inside another object, we can query in hazel cast sql predicate using the following query,

```
System.out.println(map.values(new SqlPredicate("something > 0 and complexMember.someString like 'val%'")));
```

But If the Class A has list of Class B how to query inside the list using the sql predicate?

Or any other way is there to achieve this use case.

Thanks and Regards,
Harry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the concept called predicate, Which can be implemented to any class and write our own logic in it.

Look into my code,

```
public class ListPredicate implements Predicate<String,Object>{

private Set<String> switchIds = null;

public ListPredicate(Set<String> switchIds) {
    this.switchIds = switchIds;
}

@Override
public boolean apply(Entry<String, Object> mapEntry) {
    Container container = (Container) mapEntry.getValue();
    for(String switchId : container.getFrameSwitchIdList()) {
        if(switchIds.contains(switchId)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

use your own predicate as query,

```
Collection<Container> containerList = containerMap.values(new ListPredicate(switchIds));
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no support for collection/map access inside the SqlPredicate. But you can call a no-arg method. So if you can add your logic to a method, you can say a.foobar where foobar is your method.

Example:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

    IMap<String,Person> persons = hz.getMap("persons");
    persons.put("old", new Person(30));
    persons.put("young", new Person(20));


    Collection<Person> result = persons.values(new SqlPredicate("theAge>20"));

    System.out.println(result.size());
}

public static final class Person implements Serializable{
    int age;

    public Person(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int theAge(){
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
}
```